# Inconsistant NIntegrate results for Sphere of Charge

Tags: numerical-integration

I am working on a physics problem: finding the total electric field energy in and outside of a ball of charge.  The charge density inside is constant and totals q1, the charge density outside is zero.  By closed form integration, the ratio of the total energy outside to the total energy inside is 5:1.  If I cast the problem as a function of r, everything works fine.  When I switch to Cartisian (which I will need to do when I have more than one ball), I get the correct ratio IF I don't make the radius too small.  But things go awry when the radius is too small.

```
a = 5 10^-11; 
q1 = 1.602 * 10^-19;
eps0 = 8.85 * 10^-12;  
JoulesToEV = 6.2415093433 * 10^18;
rhoV[r_] = If[r < a, q1/(4/3 \[Pi] a^3) , 0]
(* Constant charge density inside, no charge outside *)

qEnclosed[r_]  = Integrate[ 4 \[Pi] r^2 rhoV[r], r]

(* from here on it is Cartesian *)
eFieldMagnitude[x_, y_, z_] = (qEnclosed[  Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] ]/
       (4 \[Pi] eps0 (x^2  + y^2  + z^2))) 

eEnergyCartesian[x_, y_, z_] = 0.5 * eps0  (eFieldMagnitude[x, y, z] )^2
```

Now I have the energy density everywhere, and I can do the integrations, and compare in and outside.  Starting with the inside, I use Boole to restrict the volume to inside the ball.

```
energyInside = 
  NIntegrate[JoulesToEV eEnergyCartesian[x, y, z]  Boole[
Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] < a], {x, -a, a}, {y, -a, a}, {z, -a, a}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 7, 
Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10000, 
Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}]
```

This gives 2.88066 which is CORRECT, I know from closed form integration.  Now outside, where now I use Boole to mask of the ball itself:

```
energyOutside = 
NIntegrate[ JoulesToEV eEnergyCartesian[x, y, z] 
Boole[ Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 ] > a], 
{x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity],  \[Infinity]}, 
{z, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, PrecisionGoal -> 12, 
Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10000, 
Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}]
```

This gives 7.20164, the calculated energy outside.  7.20164 / 2.88066 = 2.5, which is half the correct ratio.  If I keep everything the same, but now use a = 5 10^(-5) or bigger, the ratio is correct.  There is a numerical issue here somewhere, I just can't see it!  Thanks.  If I had any hair left I'd have torn it out by now.

Comment: I'm guessing that since most your quantities are given like e.g. `q1 = 1.602 * 10^-19;`, _Mathematica_ is using machine precision, roughly 15 decimal digits on most computers. You are computing `a^3` inside `rhoV`, so probably when you divide `q1` by the denominator containing `a^3` you get many digits wrong when `a == 5*10^-11`. But I'm not sure. You should scale your units anyways, if you want to keep your hair in the long run :p

Comment: LOL thank you.  It is gone though.  Jack

Comment: That DID work.  Changed over to microns, so now 10^-5 rather than 10^-11.  OK, so machine accuracy of 15 digits is what did me in.  Thanks again, Jack